# Get a message *that*?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, syntactic-analysis

> My father has got a message that he had received 50000rs.

Is this sentence meaningful or not??
Can I use "he had received 50,000rs" after "that"?
If not, please send me the correct alternative sentence.

Comment: My father ***received*** a message informing him of receipt of 50000rs. The problem with your construction (as I see it) is the odyssey it takes us on in tense and verb. What did your father receive? Both a message (and a sum of money)... when did the two events occur? What is it you intend to convey? Also, your title is **terrible**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks for your answer. I am sorry about the given title. I am literally new to the stack overflow and also this is my first question. when I was asked to give a title, I am not sure of it. So I had given something else. Sorry about it. Hereafter I do give a title which is apt for the question.

Comment: If you say 'has got a message' you need to say 'has received' (or 'had got a message that he had received').

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! You might find [the English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) a valuable resource.

Answer (score 1):

Your father received a message informing him that he had received 50000rs.

Your father received a message: he had received 50000rs.

I think the duplication of the word received is the potential problem. Is there another word that will work? Received a message is pretty basic usage. How about something different on the other side?

Your father received a message that 50000rs had been deposited in his account. (?)

Your father received a message that 50000rs had arrived. (?)